# How long is the running time of code in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, time

I was required to calculate approximately how long will it take to an avg computer to run this code, assuming the speed of the loop is linear (my teacher told me to assume it, I know it's not true, but we are beginners so..):

```
num = 2**100
cnt = 0
import time
t0 = time.clock()
for i in range(num):
    cnt = cnt+1

t1 = time.clock()
print("running time: ", t1-t0, " sec")
```

I waited for 3 hours and didn't get anything, so, as people advised me to do, I calculated it for a smaller input: `2**20`. This took 0.24478681215692052 seconds.

Now, I tried to continue the calculation in 2 ways that I think must get me the SAME result, but they aren't.

1. if I assume the speed of the loop is linear, to calculate `2**100` I simply have to calculate `(0.24478681215692052)^5`, because `(2**20)**5 = 2**100`.

   the result I got was: 0.000878901251447358 seconds (which is really not logical)
2. I tried another way:

   - `2**20` - 0.24478681215692052 sec
   - `2**100` - ?

   and multiply like this:

   ```
   2**100 * 0.24478681215692052 / 2**20
   ```

   and got: 296101054897497890198453.29788130608283648 seconds by using [this calculator for big numbers](http://keisan.casio.com/calculator).

how is it possible that I got 2 different answers? and neither seem really logical?

Comment: `if I assume the speed of the loop is linear, to calculate 2*100 I simply have to calculate (0.24478681215692052)^5, because (2*20)*5=2**100` That's not a valid algebraic calculation.

Comment: 2**20 = 0.24478681215692052 , now we ^5 both of the sides. why isn't it valid?

Comment: `2**20 = 0.24478681215692052` Is it true that 2^20 **equals** .2447? Are you sure?

Comment: Because `2**20 != 0.2447868`. Answer #2 is correct.

Comment: `0.2447...` is the **run-time** while `2**20` is the **iterations**...do you see the difference?

Comment: @CnR Among other things mentioned above, note that `2*20` is extremely different than `2**20`, which your math seems to assume

Comment: wow sorry I feel a bit embarrassed. thanks.. but about answer#2, could it be such a big number..

Comment: @CnR, yes, because 2**100 is gigantic.  It's 1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376.  It would take you a long time to count that high too ;-)

Comment: I'm declaring `2**100` to be **a boogol™** (binary googol). Well, okay, probably already exists, but I put the "™" on it

Answer (score 1):

```
    x**y * x**z = x**(y + z)
```

Lets prove it

```
    x**y + x**z = (x * ...y times... * x) * (x * ...z times... * x) = 
    = (x * ...y+1 times... * x) * (x * ...z-1 times... * x) = 
    = ... = (x * ...y+z times... * x) = x**(y + z)
```

That's why

```
    2**100 = 2**(20 + 80) = 2**20 * 2**80
```

So,

```
    f(2**100) = f(2**20) * 2**80 = 0.24478681215692052 * 0.24478681215692052 =
    = 2.9592909751765742e+23 seconds
```

Comment: So what's the run time?

Comment: about 2.9592909751765742e+23 seconds

Comment: From your first line `2**100 == (2**20) * (2**20) * (2**20) * (2**20) * (2**20)`, so wouldn't the run time be much shorter than that? It appears to take less than a second on my computer. The answer printed was `1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376`.

Comment: Lets consider that f(n) gets us runtime time for n iterations and that f(5 * n) = f(n) * 5. 

In that case f(2**20) ~ 0.25 sec, so f(2**100) = f(2**20 * 2**80) = f(2*20) * 2**80 = 0.25 * 2**80 = 2**78 sec

Comment: Well...guess the only thing further I can say is I think your logic must be wrong.

Comment: hmm, why? it's elementar algebra